# Reg Exp - Matching word expect if there's a number or letter in front

Tags: regex

I want to write a regExp that only matches number (2) :

```
1)bincdf(2)
2)2*df(2) 
3)2df(2)  
3)2+df(2)
```

I working in as3, and I have a list of strings arr=['df','hsa','ksp'...]

Im matching those because I want to replace them, but the thing is there's not allowed to be any numbers or letters in front or behind. Behind there MUST be a '('.

So I would like to have the following result for the string = 'df':

```
2+df(2 -> TRUE
f+df(s -> TRUE

2+df2 -> FALSE
2*df+ -> FALSE
2+3df(2 -> FALSE
2-dF(2 -> FALSE
2-DF(2 -> FALSE
4+sdf(2 -> FALSE
```

++++++
PLEASE NOTICE
I want to replace the string that I pass 'df', so I ONLY want to match the string 'df'.

SO \frac(df(x) + 1,x) SHOULD ONLY MATCH the 'df(' part. So for example: if I want to replace the 'df' with '\df'. I would get:

```
\frac(\df(x) + 1,x)
```

after replace

I have tried using the ? regexp operator but I can't figure out the correct expression.

I greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Can you add what you have tried? Why is this true? `f+df(s -> TRUE` It does not contain a 2 or `(2)` Should all the first 4 examples match? Is `1)` part of the example string?

Comment: it's true because it matches a df with a '(' behind df and none-letter-none-number in front of df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. `(?<=[^0-9a-z])df(?=\()`

[This ia a Demo on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/QexPmk/2)

Comment: Thanks for response, it might work, but not in actionscript 3. I have to be able to make the string a variable that I insert into the expression:

In my code it would be like:

var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("^.*?[^0-9a-z]"+'df'+"\(.*?$","gm");
trace(pattern.test('bimcdf(x)'),pattern.test('2+df(x)'))

They both return false. I think I'm breaking the regexp when writing it as a string

Comment: ok this works: new RegExp("^.*?[^0-9a-z]"+'df'+"\\\(.*?$","gm"); 
Could you tell me the difference between \\\(.*?$.   and  \\\(      ?

Comment: Need to escape twice, the first is the escape in JavaScript, the second is the escape in the regular expression

Comment: ok no - I guess I didn't express myself clear enough in my question - I'm using the regexp to REPLACE strings, but I didn't write clearly enough that I want to ONLY replace the string 'df' (or any other string I pass). 

I have experimented with your regexp and it's too greedy. 

for the string 'sqrt': 
^.*?[^0-9a-z]sqrt\(.*?$
it will match the entire (and replace the entire string): 
[trace] BEFORE REPLACE  \frac(sqrt(x) + 1,x)
[trace] AFTER  REPLACE. \sqrt(x) + 1,x)

The result I was after is: \frac(\sqrt(x) + 1,x) 
Your regexp takes everything in front and replaces that asswell.

Comment: yes that's what I mean ... could I ask you one last time. I actually also wanted to match the '('.  ... so actually 'df(' should be match - is there a way to do that? Thanks man you've been a great help.

Comment: ok just played a bit with it. I think this:
(?<=[^0-9a-zA-Z])df\( 

Does the trick - do you agree? Or does this do something that I havn't thought of?

Comment: `(?<=[^0-9a-z])df\(` regular expression can match `df(`